# Active Directory Credentials Over LAN

Tags: php, security, web, active-directory

If you're connecting to Active Directory on an internal website using PHP, what security considerations need to be made? Will the site need SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a LAN is *more* secure than the internet, that doesn't make it *fully secure*. Similarly although AD logins are *trickier* to spoof than plaintext username/passwords, they aren't *impossible* to spoof.

You'd hope you can trust your staff, but it's good practice to use SSL on any website that includes any form of sensitive data, including but not limited to anything related to user logon - the performance hit is negligible and it negates almost all risk of anyone (internal or external) snooping on the data.

You're probably safe to skip SSL if the page is just the canteen menu for the day (although if someone performs a man in the middle attack and tells me it's Lamb Hotpot when it isn't, heads will roll), but if it's not obviously non-sensitive information, there's little reason to not use SSL

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Okay, so is the risk that a man in the middle could get your credentials if not SSL, or just that they could login as you. I'm guessing they could actually get your credentials as they get send using POST from client to server in plain text?

Comment: I don't believe they could get your credentials, but they may be able to log in as you (or even, potentially, log in as you to *other* systems). The specifics of LDAP etc aren't my area of expertise though, so I wouldn't like to promise you that either way

Comment: Thanks a lot. Neither are mine! Ha. I have some basic knowledge of PHP and have used / modified a script to login using LDAP, but my knowledge of web security is something I need to learn.

Comment: "You're probably safe to skip SSL if the page is just the canteen menu for the day" I'd argue the opposite: Even boring stuff should be encrypted (but with TLS 1.2 not SSL).